# ThreeJS- TypeError: material.customProgramCacheKey is not a function

Tags: typescript, three.js

I'm getting an error

> TypeError: material.customProgramCacheKey is not a function

The error is shown when the function `this.animate()` is called. Except when the URL is empty then there is no error. Where does that error come from I don't use material or `customProgramCacheKey`.

Is this because the object doesn't have material. I also checked the three.js documentation but I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

```
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  private loader: THREEFULL.OBJLoader;
  private scene : THREE.Scene = new THREE.Scene()
  private renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true})
  private width =  window.innerWidth/1.5
  private height = window.innerHeight/1.7
  private objects = [];
  private camera: THREE.Camera = null
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas : ElementRef;
  object = localStorage.getItem('obj');
  mtl = localStorage.getItem('mtl');
  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    
   this.showObject(); 
       
    this.basic();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
    this.renderer.setSize(this.width,this.height)
    this.renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xeeeeee))
  }
  showObject(){

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90,this.width/this.height, 1, 15000)
    this.camera.position.set(100,10,100)
    this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position)

    let light = new THREE.PointLight()
    light.position.set(10000,10000,10000)
    this.scene.add(light)

    
    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8, 18);
    light.position.set(-3,6,-3);
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
    light.shadow.camera.far = 25;
    this.scene.add(light);
    this.scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(5000))

    const byteNumbers = new Array(this.object.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.object.length; i++) {
       byteNumbers[i] = this.object.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'model/obj'}));
    

    this.loader = new THREEFULL.OBJLoader()
    this.loader.load(url,obj=>{
      this.scene.add(obj);
      (obj as THREE.Group).children.forEach(o => this.objects.push(o));
    
     this.animate(obj,0.01) 
    })
  }
  private animate(obj: THREE.Object3D, angle:number) {
    obj.scale.x = 3
    obj.scale.y = 3
    obj.scale.z = 3
    obj.translateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,2,-10),0.2)

    this.render();
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate(obj,angle))
  }
  private render() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
  }
}
```

Comment: afaik this happens during the construction of the asset loaded. I'm not sure of a good solution but you may attempt loading THREE.OBJLoader using a different import/require mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

> private loader:THREEFULL.OBJLoader;

Please do not import `OBJLoader` from third-party repos. You can import it from the `three` npm package like the core library. The ES6 import looks like so:

```js
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';

//

this.loader = new OBJLoader();
```

If you are using other classes from `THREEFULL`, use the same approach as above.